Can (neo)vim notify me when a file I'm editing is opened elsewhere?
Let's say I have a file open in (neo)vim instance A. If I open that file in (neo)vim instance B, I'm notified in that instance (B) with a warning that the file is already being edited elsewhere (or, that a backup / swap file already exists -- in neovim the warning I get is W325: Ignoring swapfile from Nvim process 1234567). Sometimes, I ignore this and open it anyway.
I know that there are ways I can add checks so that I'm notified in instance A if the file is changed elsewhere, or even if the undofile / swapfile is changed (not sure whether there's anything built in, but I could find a way to watch the file itself for changes that don't correspond with a change made in the editor). There are a billion questions about that, and that's not what I'm interested in.
What I would like to know is whether there is a way I can have a similar warning appear in instance A if the file is opened in instance B, apart from polling to check whether there's an alternate swap file every few seconds, eg if instance A's swapfile is %path%to%file.swp and instance B's is %path%to%file.swo, so instance A could check for any files named %path%to%file.sw[^p], but this is computationally costly to do constantly.

See :help :checktime and also :help timestamp to detect when a file has been changed (not just opened) outside of Vim. It's not 100% what you ask for but very close and maybe you could [edit] and tell us in which way this doesn't work for you. Also, I'd not worry about computational cost, stating a file is relatively cheap.

Vim comes with the editexisting package which can help with this

What you could do:

Use the SwapExists event to catch the event and propose your own prompt.
Depending of what the user select (e.g. e edit the file anyway)
Use the vim --serverlist shell commands to discover what are the other vim instance running
Use the vim --servername servername --remote-send ":echo 'The file ... is being edited by another instance of Vim'<CR>" command to inform the other instance.

I don't know how to identify which other instance edit the culprit file in Vim. With Neovim you can use the neovim python package to query the other instances and discover which one to contact.
